# About Theano.tensor

Tags: python

Recently I use theano to create a gragh whitch is used for identifying flowers, however, the output of theano's inner function seem not be the type that I expect, for example:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
sum = theano.tensor.sum(a, axis = 1)
sum_array = numpy.asarray(sum, dtype = numpy.float32)
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, simply I just want to creat an array to store the sum-result.

It just a simple example, in my project, I use the function "conv2d" and create an output after convolving the images, but I can't get the information of the output like the shape:

```
conv_out = conv2d(input, filter_shape, image_shape, ...)
output = theano.tensor.tanh(con_out, bias.dimshuffle('x','0','x','x'))
```

How can I change the 'output' into a 4D matrix and conveniently get its shape and other information?

Answer (score 0):

Theano is different from regular python in that what you are creating are symbolic functions.

You need call Theano.function() for the symbolic function to be compiled. Then you need to call the resulting function with parameters.